# Concept: Using Bluetooth connection to authenticate users

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

This is mostly a conceptual question but I was wondering if it would be possible to use a successful connection between two devices via Bluetooth as a trigger for authentication? Eg. If you have a Bluetooth link between your phone and an IOT device, so if you were in range of the IOT device with your phone, it would allow you access to the IOT device through a separate interface other than the phone itself.

Comment: "Yes or no" questions aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow. The simple answer to your question is "yes" but a more comprehensive answer would be too broad

Comment: My bad, new to asking questions on the site. was kind of hoping that someone would answer and give me a source/resources to look at to learn how to do this effectively. My fault for not clarifying that.